# WinForms Validation Without Hanging Other Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5

So, I got this problem in WinForms, at least I think its a problem, and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Basically, when I implement a `Validating` event handler for a control, I set the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to true when the control fails its validation. Example code:

```
private void NameTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    // Assume Cool Validation Logic.
    //
    // ...
    var isValid = false;
    if (!isValid) {
        e.Cancel = true;

        // Set an Error Provider Message.
        //
        // ...
    }
}
```

This cause the entire UI to hang. I can't select any other control, minimize the parent form window, or event exit the parent form window. So I found a similar question whose answer suggests implementing a `FormClosing` event handler for the parent form and set `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel` to false there.

Problem is, that event handler is never being called as long as my control is invalid. I have a feeling it might have something to do with my control hierarchy, though I am not 100% sure. If that helps here it is:

```
-- Parent Form

---- Custom User Control

------ Text Box Control (<-- Causes Hang)
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that was so simple, I actually got upset I wasted so many hours of my life banging my head against the keyboard.

Simply set a parent container's `ContainerControl.AutoValidate` property to `EnableAllowFocusChange` and problem solved. "Parent container" in this context means the container that actually houses the input controls.

If you have a control hierarchy, you can also set the `ContainerControl.AutoValidate` property to `Inherit` and simply set the outermost container to `EnableAllowFocusChange`.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use async/await or BackgroundWorker to handle your validation off the UI thread:

```
// in your init code...
textbox.TextChanged+=(s,e)=>Validate();


// and this is the Validation worker
BackgroundWorker validateWorker = null;
bool isValid = false;

private void Validate(){ 
  if (validateWorker != null){
    validateWorker.CancelAsync();
  }
  isValid = false;
  string validateValue = textbox.Text;

  BackgroundWorker localCopy = validateWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); 
  validateWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
  validateWorker.DoWork+=(s,e)=>{
    if (CoolValidationAssumed(validateValue) && !localCopy.CancellationPending)
       isValid = true;
  };
  validateWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>{
     if (!localCopy.CancellationPending && !isValid)
       textbox.Color = Colors.Red;
  }
  validationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: But won't that make `ValidateChildren()` always return true?

Comment: @9ee1 you can validate whatever you like in the back thread but you'll have to copy all the UI data into your model first and validate the model (or a temp instance of it) so that UI controls aren't accessed

Comment: I am not sure if this will work with Data Binding though. In addition, if you look at the source for `ValidateChildren()`, which by the way will be called for data binding on the UI thread, it absolutely needs an implementation of `Validating` to set `e.Cancel = true;`. Otherwise it will assume your controls are valid, and if you are using Data Binding, will allow the binding operation. Thank you though for taking the time to help, you were the only one :)

Comment: ahh... I see. You may need to implement custom validation scheme since your validation takes that long. If possible you can preload some server data on a back thread as the user is entering data in the field to speed-up the UI-thread validation (idk if that's why it's slow)